# Saving secure string in persistent environment variable

Tags: powershell, variables, securestring

So I'm wanting to save a secure string variable type for a local user. That way I can run a convertfrom-securestring to make rest api calls in a .ps1 file without the password being accessible. Is what I'm trying possible?

The code I'm using is below, but not yet working:

```
$PlainPassword = "atestpassword"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JiraCreds', $SecurePassword, "User")
```

Are environment variables only saved as strings without support for other data types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, environment variables are invariably *strings*, and a `[securestring]` instance cannot be used directly, because its string representation is simply its type name (`System.Security.SecureString`).

However, you can pipe to `ConvertFrom-SecureString` to get a (still encrypted) string representation:

```
$PlainPassword = "atestpassword" # Don't actually store this in your script.
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | 
  ConvertFrom-SecureString
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JiraCreds', $SecurePassword, "User")
```

To later use the environment variable to construct a `[pscredential]` instance (using the current user's username as an example):

```
$cred = New-Object pscredential $env:USERNAME, (ConvertTo-SecureString $env:JiraCreds)
```